# Webpack: cannot add audio (mp3)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I tried a lot to add audio to my webpack, so i can play sound every time user click on div.
Tried different ways, used loaders, but everything dont work.
JS:

```
const audio = new Audio('../../sounds/24.mp3')
audio.play()
```

Webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [
  {
test: /\.[tj]s$/,
    use: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
  {
    test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.mp3$/i,
    use: 'file-loader',
  },
],
```

}

package.json:

```
"file-loader": "^6.2.0",
```

Every time i get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/sounds/24.mp3 404 (Not Found)
```

I feel like I make a stupid mistake, but i cant realize where.